# Vim How to automatically return from user defined command

Tags: vim

I defined the following command to export file selection into `html` file and then use `Google Chrome` to open it for printing

```
command! -range WebPrint <line1>,<line2>call Print()
function! Print()
    :'<,'>TOhtml
    :wq
    :!/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome %:p.html
endfunction
```

One annoying thing is that every time I execute the command, the vim section is gone and I have to type `Ctrl-c` to go back (hitting `<Enter>` weirdly execute the command once again). If there a way to automatically return to vim section after the command is run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `:help call`:

```
    When a range is given and the function doesn't handle it
    itself, the function is executed for each line in the range,
```

Your `Print` function is defined without `range`, so it is invoked multiple times, once for each line in the selected range.

If that's not what you want, remove `<line1>,<line2>`.

See also `:help function-range-example`.

Comment: I see, thanks! Now every time after I call the function, the vim session has been transferred to a bash session saying `Press ENTER or type command to continue`. Is there a way to automatically go back to vim session?

Comment: Use `silent !/Applications/...`.  Probably also with a `redraw`.  See the last two paragraphs under `:help !cmd`.